# cumulative matrix transformation with ICP from PCL

Tags: c++, matrix-multiplication, point-cloud-library, matrix-transform

My goal is to align 3D point clouds with ICP. Somehow I have an error, I believe it is because of the cumulative matrix transformations.

For debugging I start with 2D point clouds, I created. For the creation of the point clouds, I create a random angle and sign them with cos() and sin() to a x and a y value, so I have random points on a circle. Than I use a translation and a rotation that rises iteratively for each new created image.

[image: generated point cloud]
[image: generated point cloud]

I am generating about 20 point clouds and store them in these 512*512 images. Than I want to load does images, create point clouds out of them and align them with ICP.

Now for the cumulative matrix transformation. Image at time 0 would have the Identity matrix. But ever other Image would get as transformation the matrix gathered from ICP (M) multiplied with the transformation matrix, from the last known position:
Mi = M * Mi-1

I am not sure If this is the write way, or if I have to transform back to Identity before applying a full transformation.

My results are for 10 point clouds:

[image: without ICP]
[image: with ICP]

In the first we see the gathered point clouds without ICP and in the second with ICP. I tested it before only with translations, that worked really good. And than I tested it with only rotations, and there I had way to high errors. It could be, that the rotation is to high, so ICP aligns the points wrong and than finds wrong matches.

But if I test real data, images gathered from a Xbox Kinect camera, it seems to have the same error like in my example with 2D point clouds.

So am I calculating the cumulative matrix transformation wrong? or is there maybe a different problem which I don't see?

And How should I set up my ICP correctly? I only using the setting :

```
icp.setTransformationEpsilon (1e-9);
```

And is there any other way to test it correctly?